Using low end nvidia gt 610 gpu with ffmpeg and linux ryzen 5600
Hi I am Rupesh from India and I have pc with Intel i3 10th gen 10100 and Asus prime H 510 me motherboard and I want to upgrade my PC.
I have chosen AMD Ryzen 5600 cpu which doesn't have integrated cpu and require discrete graphics card and so I have chosen zebronics GT 610 graphics card which has nvidia gt 610 gpu.
I can get Ryzen 5600 and Ryzen 5600G at the same price ie., 12500 rupees Indian currency. But the intersting point is that 5600G has 16mb l3 cache and graphics core next 7 integrated graphics. Ryzen 5600 don't have integrated graphics and has 32 mb l3 cache.
So if I can buy 5600 cpu I can get double performance than integrated graphics version cpu.
Actually most of the time I use my desktop pc in transcoding x265 hevc videos into aom av1 codec video. I don't have the habit of playing video games.
I have chosen zebronics GT 610 graphics card because it costs only 1600 rupees Indian currency and it has 30 watts TDP which comes with 2 GB GDDR3 ram.
Mainly I use my desktop pc for transcoding videos and linux programming and even I don't use it for video editing or video creation. I mean I use my pc with command line or CLI.
I have some videos with x265 codec and 500 mb size and approximately 1200*700 pixels.
While converting x265 to av1 I use 2 pass encoding in ffmpeg.
My question is " Is there any requirement for any high quality graphics card which costs thousands of india currency or hundreds of US dollars just to decode x265 or x264 video".
How much time does it take to decode 500 mb x265 video using CPU which doesn't have integrated graphics. How much CPU percentage does it take to decode.
Some people said that gt 610 will crash and cpu usage will raise upto 90 percent while decoding. Is it true.
I think that ffmpeg tool first decode the input x265 video file and store temporarily somewhere and then convert to other format like av1.
While the ffmpeg tool is decoding the input x265 video can I use the CPU which doesn't have integrated graphics or can I use low end nvidia gt 610 GPU.
Another point to mention is that high cost graphics card has two to three cooling fans and require additional power supply but gt 610 requires only one pci slot.
In the specification page of zebronics GT 610 they have given it require only 35 Watt power. Is it true if not how much watts does it take.
I am not going to stick to only GT 610 but I want to select any graphics card which costs less and which has only one cooling fan with x265 and x264 decoding.
If the graphics card fails I can buy and replace another cheap one.
Kindly try to suggest whether I can use gt 610 gpu in ffmpeg x265 and x264 decoding. If you think using graphics card requires additional cooling I am ready to use cooling cabinet.
If you say don't use any graphics card I will follow your suggestion.
Regards,
Rupesh.

Can ffmpeg decode x265 without the help of any gpu I mean software decoding and if so how much cpu percentage it takes.

Ok can you please suggest any other graphics card with lowest cost and x265 decoding.
Can I choose gt 710 or gt 730 for x265 decoding.

The GT 610 is VERY old (2012) and will not support hardware decode or encode of x265 at all, and x264 support may well be somewhat limited compared to more modern cards. It corresponds to Nvidia Purevideo 5. The graphics in Ryzen 5600G is almost 10 years newer so should be better. Also 16MB o f L3 vs 32MB L3 will not be a straight 100% boost, there will be some difference depending on the task, but definitely not a doubling in performance.

From https://bluesky-soft.com/en/dxvac/deviceInfo/decoder/nvidia.html The GT 610 can do 4K h.264 decode but not h.265 (HEVC) at all, though better models in the 600 range can decode "normal" HEVC some can only do FHD while others can do 4K, but none can do HDR content. I would not consider a 610 a worthwhile addition at any price point. Integrated graphics on any modern CPU will be better for lower cost.

You already looked into details like L3 cache size, so this is probably not needed. But just in case: You do realise that an socket LGA1200 motherboard? So you can only use intel gen 10 and gen 11 CPU's on it. For the 5600X or the 5600G you would need a socket AM4 motherboard.
